# CSS Selectors for parsing HTML in PHP

Tags: php, css, css-selectors, html-parsing

I used to use jsoup to parse html in Java. It can select and parse almost everything. I recently made a switch to PHP and I tried a couple of DOM parsers, but the css selectors are not working as expected (or, as good as jsoup). For instance, I tried to select the **About** (at the top-left corner) link of the [Google](http://google.com)'s home page using:

### 1. DOMCrawler - Symfony:

```
$crawler->filter('#hptl > a:nth-child(1)')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
Result: Empty Page
```

### 2. Simple HTML DOM:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html("https://google.com");

// Find innertext of about
foreach($html->find("#hptl > a:nth-child(1)") as $element) {
    echo $element->innertext . "<br>";
}
Result: Empty Page
```

### 3. phpQuery:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile('https://google.com');
dd($doc->find("#hptl > a:nth-child(1)")->text());
Result: Empty String
```

But if I try to select the element using [jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org), the css selector of jsoup can easily select the element.

I have tested with different selectors and in most cases they failed to select the element I want but jsoup did not. Here is an example of such a selector:

```
div.schedule_table:nth-child(8) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)
```

I usually copy the css selector from the dev tools. Am I doing something wrong in the process? If not, is there a better parser with full css selector support for PHP?

Comment: Can you show the outputted html?

Comment: @fauverism Sure. But of which one?

Comment: Did you debug the output, just to be sure? Dev tools doesn't find `#hptl > a:nth-child(1)` for me either. Might be some mutable element.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Maybe that **About** page appears only when a user is logged in and that's why we couldn't select it. But even if I open a private window and try to select another element which is accessible globally, for instance the 'Gmail` anchor tag, parsers like Simple HTML Dom cannot select it. Could you confirm you can find this element: `div.gb_Q:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)` on google.com?

Comment: I went to this site and copied the css selector (`.footer--copyright > span:nth-child(1)`) of the footer: https://itstillworks.com/. I tried to select it with simple html dom, it could not find. Then I went to http://try.jsoup.org, fetched the url, searched for the same element with same selector and the element was found.

Comment: I see you are using URL as a file name(both phpQuery and Simple Dom Parser are using `gile_get_contents` behind a scene). Have you checked if your configuration [allows that](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to you?

Comment: It does sound like Google is serving different HTML to your PHP scripts. I wonder if it could be a GeoIP thing. Are you sure you're actually getting a response from google.com and not one of their localized home pages?

Comment: @BoltClock Forget google. Can you select the copyright text of this site: http://itstillworks.com ? (Selector: `.footer--copyright > span:nth-child(1)`) with Simple HTML Dom? Tip: You can try it online on http://phpfiddle.org. Just select Simple HTML Dom when prompted.

Comment: You're right, I'm not seeing anything there either...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Google landing page has evolved a bit since the OP posted.  Nevertheless, I have had good success making a similar query with [QueryPath](https://querypath.org/).  For example:

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
$qp =html5qp('https://google.com','#footer > div > div > a:nth-of-type(3)');
print_r($qp->text());
```

returns "About Google"

Note that the content of the Google landing page depends on the `user-agent` request header.  If you want to match the page you see in your browser, you will have to download the page separately, with an appropriate `user-agent` request header.

Comment: what is that html5qp () is that default in of any php functions or do we need to implement some external libraries?

Comment: The answer uses the QueryPath library, https://querypath.org/